# Custom Fields not showing any value, just empty return

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

i'm using custom fields on wordpress to built a table.

The table code goes like this:

```
<?php 
            echo '<table>   <tr>
                <td><b>Personi / Institucioni i Dekoruar</b></td>
                <td><b>Numri i Dekretit</b></td>
                <td><b>Data e Dekretit</b></td>
                <td><b>Medalja</b></td>
            </tr>';

            while (have_posts()) : the_post();          
            $personi_ose_institucioni = get_sub_field('personi_ose_institucioni');  ?>
            <tr><td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> "><?php echo $personi_ose_institucioni.'</td>';

            $numri_i_dekretit = get_sub_field('numri_i_dekretit');
            echo '<td>'.$numri_i_dekretit.'</td>';

            $data_e_dekretit = get_sub_field('data_e_dekretit');
            echo '<td>'.$data_e_dekretit.'</td>';

            $medalja = get_sub_field('medalja');
            echo '<td>'.$medalja.'</td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><hr></td></tr>';

            endwhile; ?>
            <tr>
   <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
   <td><?php previous_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> 
   Previous ', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></td>
  <td></td>
   <td></td>
    <td><?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span> 
    ', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></td>
      <?php endif; ?>
            <tr/>
            </table>
```

the thing is this returns empty values [what that table shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfEtR.jpg)

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: any idea anybody?

Comment: get_sub_field is used for repeater fields.  What's your repeater field name called?  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: @AndrewSchultz it's called dekorime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you'd access your fields.  You can read up on the official [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) of how to access repeater fields.

```
if( have_rows('dekorime') ):

    while( have_rows('dekorime') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $var1 = get_sub_field('personi_ose_institucioni');
        $var2 = get_sub_field('numri_i_dekretit');
        echo $var1;

    endwhile;
endif;
```